# Spring Security SSO

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, glassfish, single-sign-on

I would like to include SSO to my J2EE projects. I'm trying to find a solution which does not need another server than my application server.

Here's the environment :

- Glassfish v3.1.2
- 2 identical projects using Spring MVC / Security (let's say project1 and project2)

What do projects implement :

- a simple ajax login form
- a controller with login and test methods :

  ```
  @Controller
  public class ProjectController {
      public static final String REMEMBER_ME_ACTIVE = "on";

      @Autowired
      SecurityContextRepository repository;

      @Autowired
      RememberMeServices rememberMeServices;

      @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.GET)
      public Object login(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
          System.out.println("[GET] login");
          System.out.println(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication());
          System.out.println(request.getSession().getId());

          return new ModelAndView("login");
      }

      @RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
      @ResponseBody
      public Object login(@RequestParam("j_username") String username, 
                          @RequestParam("j_password") String password,
                          @RequestParam("_spring_security_remember_me") String rememberMe,
                          HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
          System.out.println("[POST] login");
          System.out.println(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication());
          System.out.println(request.getSession().getId());

          try {

              UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, password);

              SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();

              context.setAuthentication(token);
              repository.saveContext(context, request, response);

              if (REMEMBER_ME_ACTIVE.equals(rememberMe)) {
                  rememberMeServices.loginSuccess(request, response, token);
              }

              return "OK";
          }
          catch (BadCredentialsException e) {
              return "BadCredentialsException";
          }
          catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();

              return "Exception : " + e.getMessage();
          }
      }

      @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.GET)
      public Object test(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
          System.out.println("[GET] test");
          System.out.println(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication());
          System.out.println(request.getSession().getId());

          return new ModelAndView("test");
      }
  }
  ```
- spring-security.xml :

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
            xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                     http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
                     http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">
      <!-- security config -->
      <http auto-config="false" use-expressions="true" >
          <http-basic/>

          <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="hasRole('ROLE_ANONYMOUS')"/>

          <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasAnyRole('ROLE_USER')" />

          <form-login login-page="/login"
                      login-processing-url="/spring/login"
                      authentication-failure-url="/login"
                      default-target-url="/"
                      always-use-default-target="true" />

          <remember-me services-ref="tokenBasedRememberMeServices"
                       key="XXXXXX_1234567890"
                       use-secure-cookie="true" />

          <logout logout-url="/spring/logout"
                  invalidate-session="false"
                  logout-success-url="/login" />

          <session-management invalid-session-url="/login" session-fixation-protection="newSession">
              <concurrency-control max-sessions="3"
                                   error-if-maximum-exceeded="false"
                                   expired-url="/login"
                                   session-registry-ref="sessionRegistry" />
          </session-management>
      </http>

      <beans:bean id="sessionRegistry" class="org.springframework.security.core.session.SessionRegistryImpl" />

      <!-- authentication config -->
      <authentication-manager>
          <authentication-provider ref="userAuthenticationProvider"/>
      </authentication-manager>

      <beans:bean id="userAuthenticationProvider" class="be.xxx.spring.security.UserAuthenticationProvider" />

      <beans:bean id="tokenBasedRememberMeServices" class="be.xxx.spring.security.TokenBasedRememberMeServices">
          <beans:constructor-arg name="key" value="XXXXXX_1234567890"/>
          <beans:constructor-arg name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService"/>
      </beans:bean>

      <beans:bean id="userDetailsService" class="be.xxx.spring.security.UserDetailsService" />
  </beans:beans>
  ```

Till now, I found that Glassfish was supporting SSO as written [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18930_01/html/821-2418/beacq.html) but it does not seem to work alongside Spring Security. When logged-in in project1, I can't see JSESSIONIDSSO. So when I start project2, it sends me the login form... Also tried to specify the same realm-name in web.xml but no changes.

After some googleing, I found some things about PreAuthenticationFilter but I really don't know how to implement a SSO solution with this.

Could you help me to find out a solution ?

Thanks,

Smoky

Answer (score 0):

If the projects are identical, you can always use sticky sessions and share the sessions between the projects.